# Angular/Ionic: how to align a text area?

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework

Angular 1 / Ionic 1 single page app.

I would like to have the textarea vertically aligned with other inputs, on the right of the labels of each field. I tried a  instead of the , it's different but not better.

Would you please have an idea? Many thanks!

[image: screenshot]

```
  <ion-content >
    <div class="list">
        <label class="item item-input">
            <span class="input-label">Name</span>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Smith" ng-model="entity.lastname">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
            <span class="input-label">Email</span>
            <input type="email" placeholder="john.smith@google.com" ng-model="entity.email">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
            <span>Comments</span>
            <textarea placeholder="Free text" ng-model="entity.comments"></textarea>
        </label>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

I could fix it by adding `class="input-label"` to the `<span>` tag, just like for the others.